# C# same method, but different parameters: with ref and without

Tags: c#, methods, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm an italian guy, sorry for my bad english! I wish to know if there is a way to use a method with passing a parameter by reference or by value whenever you want.

For example, if I want this method:

```
public mehtod (ref int a)
{
    //do some stuff
}
```

And this other method

```
public method (int a)
{
    //do the same stuff of method(ref int a)
}
```

There is a way to obtain the same result, but without creating two different methods with the same body? I need it because some times I want side-effects on a using "method", sometimes I want that a is not modified!

Thank you so much!

Comment: If the methods have the same body you must not be using the fact that `a` is a `ref` parameter, so why include that version at all?

Comment: @Andrew that's not really true; you can always modify a parameter value - the interesting question is: does the **caller** see the change. That does not impact the method body

Comment: @MarcGravell: That's true I suppose, good point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call the first method from the second one:

```
public void method (ref int a)
{
    //do some stuff
}

public void method(int a)
{
    method(ref a);  //do the same stuff of method(ref int a)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought the same solution 3 seconds after I made this question (but I asked this question after 15 minutes thinking about how to solve it)

Comment: Note: this might not play nicely with some languages that don't love overload just on ref - VB, IIRC

Answer (score 1):

If the return type is `void`, you can change it to **return** the modified value rather than use `ref`. Then the caller can ignore the return value or use the return value, as they choose:

```
int Method(int foo) {
   // ...
   foo = ...
   // ...
   return foo;
}
```

With:

```
Method(a);
```

Vs

```
a = Method(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   static void callingMethod()
    {
        int a = 0;
        method(a); // original a is not modified

        // or

        method(ref a); // a is modified
    }

    static void method(int a)
    {
        method(ref a);
    }

    static void method(ref int a)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iam not sure why you want to do that.. but there is one way you can do by

1. Add one more parameter Boolean flag to modify or not to the following

> public mehtod (ref int a,bool modify)

then inside it if modify passed is false then inside declare a new variable and assign only the value and use it 
like int b = a;
and use b for processing at the end based on the flag you update ref variable or leave it